# Utilization of disks for virtualization

Tags: hard-drive, debian, ssd, raid

Which disk components/configuration would work best for my scenario?

I have a 1U server that supports 4 drives. It has 2 ports for SATAII and 2 ports for SATAIII. It's an 8 core Atom with 2.4GHz and 16GB DDR3.

The OS will run Debian 8 with QEMU-KVM. The VM's will run Debian 8 as well, about 30GB chunks and host services such as NTP, OpenVPN, FreeSwitch, APT-Caching, etc.

I have 4x 750GB WD Black 2.5" drives and 2x 256GB Samsung 850 Pro SSD's to choose from.

Currently I have 4x 750GB in RAID 10 and it runs slow with lots of disk i/o - especially when doing software installs, upgrades, or if errors occur and it logs heavily.

My initial thought was to software RAID 1 the 256GB Samsung SSD's and RAID 1 the 750GB WD's. Then install the host OS on the 750GB array and the VM's on the SSD's using part of the 750GB raid array for SWAP and /var/log.

Or should I choose a different route?

Comment: An SSD Raid is no faster than a single SSD. This is something to consider. If you need the extra capacity, span the 2 drives (dynamic disk).

Comment: I'm aware the SSD RAID 1 wouldn't provide any performance improvement in my setup. The RAID 1 was just to protect against single drive failure.